# How to specify docker image's DNS?

Tags: dns, docker

Now I have a lot of docker containers running on my host machine, and inside the containers, dns-look-up is very slow. So I want to change the containers' DNS.

I've known two possible ways:

1) use command-line argument '-dns'
2) modify `/etc/default/docker` -> `DOCKER_OPTS` and restart docker daemon

The above two ways force me to either change my `docker run` command, or restart daemon which will stop all currently running containers. I cannot accept these.

So, is there any way else to change a docker image's DNS? (re-run an image is acceptable)

Comment: What's wrong with using the --dns command line argument when you run the image?

Comment: @dukebody I'm managing those containers by my own program, so if I use --dns, then I have to change my code and restart my service.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way by now... See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2267

Comment: Your statement "Now I have a lot of docker containers ... DNS look-up is very slow" seems suspicious to me. It's inconceivable that searching ten thousand names takes even one millisecond. Better to track down what is really causing the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to `/etc/resolv.conf` inside a container. Perhaps `EXEC` a script that does that and then runs the real program.